# How to arrange first three columns of the dataframe in one column with fixed rows while making plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tibble, facet-wrap

I need to create a density plot and QQ plot for the dataset contains triplicate values of columns. So the plot should contain 3 rows and the first three columns in the dataframe need to be in the first column of the plot (which represents the replicate values).

The sample data is

```
structure(list(ID = c("P19882", "P38999", "P34227", "Q12335", 
"P40893", "P33416", "Q04947", "Q12074", "P38116", "P32598", "P38221", 
"P52910", "P0CX51;P0CX52", "Q02805", "P50861", "Q02821", "P53691", 
"P19414", "Q04013", "Q07799", "P47039"), `1_3ng` = c(964860000, 
46301000, 135090000, 126280000, 96191000, 91552000, 75231000, 
76684000, 6150500, 21904000, 55134000, 231070000, 259060000, 
7304500, 180320000, 22025000, 79510000, 677560000, 5994400, 18950000, 
3468200), `2_3ng` = c(1074500000, 42888000, 125590000, 1.27e+08, 
68911000, 93280000, 66457000, 69568000, 4848600, 20342000, 52573000, 
242230000, 286970000, 5770200, 190140000, 22305000, 87598000, 
673050000, 6459300, 21634000, 3115400), `3_3ng` = c(1021200000, 
56550000, 117190000, 124730000, 69026000, 80712000, 55917000, 
71989000, 5390500, 19299000, 51348000, 213050000, 254080000, 
6976000, 181280000, 20951000, 83504000, 664590000, 6155300, 21158000, 
2940600), `4_7-5ng` = c(846340000, 34713000, 95928000, 121440000, 
16256000, 63182000, 46570000, 59008000, 1465600, 24838000, 48464000, 
176140000, 175320000, 8738500, 120870000, 24496000, 75694000, 
524780000, 4373900, 16281000, 5801700), `5_7-5ng` = c(921740000, 
35240000, 109990000, 111250000, 39047000, 74125000, 51027000, 
65971000, 3027100, 36529000, 39712000, 179630000, 218240000, 
8092500, 152610000, 26032000, 62681000, 587100000, 4887000, 18454000, 
3811100), `6_7-5ng` = c(908710000, 38475000, 106400000, 113590000, 
36745000, 74175000, 48912000, 64201000, 3073300, 39069000, 40650000, 
206350000, 220280000, 8673100, 154260000, 30254000, 61422000, 
617900000, 5561000, 17102000, 5486600), `7_10ng` = c(964860000, 
46301000, 135090000, 126280000, 96191000, 91552000, 75231000, 
76684000, 6150500, 21904000, 55134000, 231070000, 259060000, 
7304500, 180320000, 22025000, 79510000, 677560000, 5994400, 18950000, 
3468200), `8_10ng` = c(1074500000, 42888000, 125590000, 1.27e+08, 
68911000, 93280000, 66457000, 69568000, 4848600, 20342000, 52573000, 
242230000, 286970000, 5770200, 190140000, 22305000, 87598000, 
673050000, 6459300, 21634000, 3115400), `9_10ng` = c(1021200000, 
56550000, 117190000, 124730000, 69026000, 80712000, 55917000, 
71989000, 5390500, 19299000, 51348000, 213050000, 254080000, 
6976000, 181280000, 20951000, 83504000, 664590000, 6155300, 21158000, 
2940600), `10_15ng` = c(846340000, 34713000, 95928000, 121440000, 
16256000, 63182000, 46570000, 59008000, 1465600, 24838000, 48464000, 
176140000, 175320000, 8738500, 120870000, 24496000, 75694000, 
524780000, 4373900, 16281000, 5801700), `11_15ng` = c(921740000, 
35240000, 109990000, 111250000, 39047000, 74125000, 51027000, 
65971000, 3027100, 36529000, 39712000, 179630000, 218240000, 
8092500, 152610000, 26032000, 62681000, 587100000, 4887000, 18454000, 
3811100), `12_15ng` = c(908710000, 38475000, 106400000, 113590000, 
36745000, 74175000, 48912000, 64201000, 3073300, 39069000, 40650000, 
206350000, 220280000, 8673100, 154260000, 30254000, 61422000, 
617900000, 5561000, 17102000, 5486600)), row.names = 500:520, class = "data.frame")
```

I have used the below function for generating the density plot,

```
Densityplot_data <- function (data){
  variable <- value <- NULL
  
  new_data <- as.data.frame(data)
  new_data <- new_data[,-1]
  options(warn = -1)
  
  density_plot <- new_data %>%
    tibble::as.tibble() %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(order_hlp = as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]","",variable))) %>% 
    dplyr::arrange(order_hlp) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(variable_fac = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable))) %>% 
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x=value) ) +
    ggplot2::geom_density (fill= "#69b3a2") +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable_fac, scales="free", nrow = 3)+
    ggplot2::theme_gray()+
    ggplot2::theme(text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 20))
  return(plotly::ggplotly(density_plot))
}
```

This function returned the below plot,

```
Densityplot_data(data)
```

[image]

Like this I have used the below function for generating the QQ plot,

```
QQplot_data <- function(data){
  Observed = stats::rnorm(nrow(data))
  new_dat <- cbind(Observed,data[,-1])
  colnames(data) <- c("ID", "1_3ng",    "2_3ng",    "3_3ng",    "4_7-5ng",  "5_7-5ng",
                         "6_7-5ng", "7_10ng",   "8_10ng",   "9_10ng",   "10_15ng",  "11_15ng",  "12_15ng")
  plot<-new_dat %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value, -Observed) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(order_hlp = as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "",variable))) %>% 
    
    dplyr::mutate(variable_fac = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable)))%>%  
    dplyr::arrange(order_hlp)  

    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(sample = value, color = variable))+
    ggplot2::stat_qq_line(col = "red",
                          lwd = 0.5)+
    ggplot2::theme(text = ggplot2::element_text(size=16))+
    ggplot2::stat_qq()+
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable)+
    ggplot2::ylab('Observed values')+
    ggplot2::xlab('Expected under normality')
  return(plotly::ggplotly(plot))
}
QQplot_data(data)
```

And I got the plot like below,
[image]

In both of the above plots, the column order is not representing the first three columns in the same one column. Suppose the dataset contains the 12 columns I need the following order of plots,

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

How to change the above-mentioned codes to get this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the approach you used was working for the data in one of your previous questions. With different column names you have to adjust the approach. In the code below I first use the formula

```
(as.numeric(factor(variable, names(data)[-1])) - 1) %% 3
```

to split the columns into groups based on the column position and hence does not rely on the column names. Then I add the row order using `group_by` and `row_number`. Afterwards `arrange` by both columns and set the order of the `factor` levels

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

QQplot_data <- function(data) {
  Observed <- stats::rnorm(nrow(data))
  new_dat <- cbind(Observed, data[, -1])
  colnames(data) <- c(
    "ID", "1_3ng", "2_3ng", "3_3ng", "4_7-5ng", "5_7-5ng",
    "6_7-5ng", "7_10ng", "8_10ng", "9_10ng", "10_15ng", "11_15ng", "12_15ng"
  )
  
  dat_plot <- new_dat %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value, -Observed) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      position = as.numeric(factor(variable, names(data)[-1])),
      order_col = (position - 1) %% 3
    ) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(order_col, position) |> 
    dplyr::mutate(order_row = dplyr::row_number()) |> 
    dplyr::ungroup() |> 
    dplyr::arrange(order_row, order_col) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = unique(variable)))
  
  dat_plot %>%
    ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(sample = value, color = variable)) +
    ggplot2::stat_qq_line(
      col = "red",
      lwd = 0.5
    ) +
    ggplot2::theme(text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 16)) +
    ggplot2::stat_qq() +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~variable) +
    ggplot2::ylab("Observed values") +
    ggplot2::xlab("Expected under normality")
  
  plotly::ggplotly()
}
QQplot_data(data)
```

[image]

Comment: It is fine. But I need the code which can create the above kind of plots which are not depending on the column names. Because the column names may vary from data to data. I need to arrange the first three columns of the dataset into the first column of the plot irrespective of the column names. So can you suggest for this...

Comment: I just have made an edit which does rely on the column names.

Comment: Thank you @stefan. Finally it is working now...